# script to put a hyperlink in a cell to go to another sheet of same worksheet

Tags: url, hyperlink

My script creates a new sheet within a worksheet and I‘d like then to put a hyperlink in a cell of the “home” sheet pointing to this newly created sheet
Here’s the snippet that writes the link in the cell. It works ok but opens the sheet in a new tab every time I click on link. Is there a way for this link to direct to the new sheet *within* in same tab?
Thanks ever so much

```
var refSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName(nomSheet);
var refSheetId = refSheet.getSheetId().toString();
var ssUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getUrl()+"#gid="+refSheetId;
var cellLink = ss.getSheetByName("Sorties").getRange(Alast,57);
var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
.setText("Inscriptions")
.setLinkUrl(ssUrl)
.build();
cellLink.setRichTextValue(richValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the line creating the url with this line (omitting spreadsheet name)and it did the trick!
var ssUrl = "#gid="+refSheetId;

It seems that if you put a complete url in the link of the cell, Sheets systematically opens the link in a new tab, as if it was another file, so that you end up with multiple instances of the same (work)sheet. I found out that if you omit the name/ID of the worksheet, and only build the link with the string "#gid" + the sheet id inside the worksheet, Sheets looks up first among the sheets of the active worksheet and, if found, replaces the active sheet with the sheet of the link.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).